# terraform 0.9.4 vs. 0.11.7: there are differences in the implicit dependencies?

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform Version v0.11.7, and code looks like this:

```
resource "vault_policy" "vault-auth" {
    name        = "vault-auth"
    policy      = <<_EOT
        path "secret/approle-acl/*" {
            capabilities = ["read", "list"]
        }
        path "auth/approle/role/*" {
            capabilities = ["update"]
        }
    _EOT
}

resource "vault_generic_secret" "approle-vault-auth" {
    path        = "auth/approle/role/vault-auth"
    data_json   = <<_EOT
        {
            "bind_secret_id":   false,
            "bound_cidr_list":  "127.0.0.0/24",
            "policies":         "${vault_policy.vault-auth.name}",
            "period":           1200
        }
    _EOT
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "vault-auth-approle-id" {
    path = "${vault_generic_secret.approle-vault-auth.path}/role-id"
}

resource "consul_keys" "vault-auth-approle-id" {
    key {
        path    = "vault-auth/vault-approle-id"
        value   = "${lookup(data.vault_generic_secret.vault-auth-approle-id.data, "role_id")}"
        delete  = "true"
    }
}
```

I used this piece of code with Terraform 0.9.4 and it works as expected, but with 0.11.7 I see the errors:

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

module.roles.data.vault_generic_secret.vault-auth-approle-id: 1 error(s) occurred:

module.roles.data.vault_generic_secret.vault-auth-approle-id: data.vault_generic_secret.vault-auth-approle-id: No secret found at "auth/approle/role/vault-auth/role-id"
```

In my opinion, this might be correlated with Error [Checking for Output Values](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-11.html#error-checking-for-output-values), because we don't have a value when we do refresh.

Or what happens here, because I'm not sure where I'm wrong.

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
terraform init
terraform apply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be dumping your data_json into 'vault-auth' and then when you're trying to call your secrets via path you are using 'auth/approle/role/vault-auth/role-id'. Try something like this instead:

```
resource "vault_generic_secret" "approle-vault-auth" {
    path        = "auth/approle/role/vault-auth/role-id"
    data_json   = <<_EOT
        {
            "bind_secret_id":   false,
            "bound_cidr_list":  "127.0.0.0/24",
            "policies":         "${vault_policy.vault-auth.name}",
            "period":           1200
        }
    _EOT
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "vault-auth-approle-id" {
    path = "${vault_generic_secret.approle-vault-auth.path}"
}
```

Now you are dumping your secrets into 'role-id' and are then trying to retrieve them from the same endpoint. Hope this helps!

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vault/r/generic_secret.html